# Is there a way to start a script on the publisher when synchronization starts?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I am using merge replication with pull subscriptions and Web Sync.

What is the easiest way to start a SQL script on the publication database when a subscriber starts the synchronization process?

There is this, [`sp_addscriptexec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360.aspx), but that specifies a script to run at the subscription database which isn't what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in or easy way to do this with Web Synchronization.  You're best bet is to programmatically monitor Merge Agent sessions at the Publisher/Distributor using [sp_replmonitorhelpmergesession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187726.aspx) and [sp_replmonitorhelpmergesessiondetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186970.aspx).  You can script this out and poll on a schedule.